# CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(Wack_ModeSelection::ParticleAnimation)); this callback showing error in cocos2d 3.0

Tags: ios, c++11, cocos2d-x

Please give the alternate of `FiniteTimeAction*`

`callFunc=CCCallFunc::create(this,callfunc_selector(Wack_ModeSelection::ParticleAnimation));`

error :

> Static_cast from 'void' (Wack_ModeSelection::*)(CCObject *)to
>   cocos2d::SEL_Callfunc (aka void(cocos2d::Ref::*(()) is not allowed

Comment: Provide the complete compiler error message.

Comment: error : Static_cast from 'void' (Wack_ModeSelection::*)(CCObject *)to cocos2d::SEL_Callfunc (aka void(cocos2d::Ref::*(()) is not allowed

Comment: Now show the declaration of `Wack_ModeSelection::ParticleAnimation()`.

Comment: i got the solution ...thanks for rply