# CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(DressMe_LevelManager::removeTheObjectFromArray)),NULL)); giving error in cocos3.9

Tags: ios, c++11, cocos2d-x

```
ActionInterval *scale1 = ScaleTo::create(.05f, 1.3f);
ActionInterval *scale2 = ScaleTo::create(.1f, 0.0f); 
runAction(CCSequence::create(
    scale1,
    scale2,
    CCDelayTime::create(.8f),
    CCCallFuncN::create(this,callfuncN_selector(DressMe_LevelManager::removeTheObjectFromArray)),
NULL)); 


void DressMe_LevelManager:: removeTheObjectFromArray(DressMe_objectClass *l_obj){
    m_ptrArrayElements->removeObject(l_obj);
    l_obj = NULL;
    MoveBakTheCart();
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
static_cast from void (DressMe_LevelManager::*) (Dress_ObjectClass *) to cocos2d::SEL_CallfuncN (aka void (cocos2d:Ref::*) (cocos2d::Node *) ) is not allowed
```

Comment: I'm sure it's similar to [the issue you had before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527815/cccallfunccreatethis-callfunc-selectorwack-modeselectionparticleanimation).

Comment: but here i am not able to solve.i tried every possible thing.i just beginner.please help me

Comment: What was the solution last time?  You just said "i have fixed it, bye" with the last issue.

Comment: instead of callFunc i used callFuncN and used CC_CALLBACK_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change action as below:

```
runAction(CCSequence::create(
                                 scale1,
                                 scale2,
                                 CCDelayTime::create(.8f),
                                 CallFuncN::create(CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::removeTheObjectFromArray, this)),
                                 NULL));
```

The `callfuncN_selector` is deprecated which accepts function having parameter of type `Node*`. So as `removeTheObjectFromArray` accpets object of `Dress_ObjectClass`, it gives error.